# Custom a BigQuery query in order to retrieve records for a specified date with a few seconds of time interval

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query which allows me to retrieve the actions made by a user on an object :

```
SELECT
  protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,
  protopayload_auditlog.methodName,
  receiveTimestamp,
  protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail,

FROM `my_projet.my_dataset.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_*`
WHERE
  protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail LIKE "%visa%" AND
  resource.labels.bucket_name = "my_bucket" AND
  protopayload_auditlog.resourceName LIKE "%objects/a.csv%"
ORDER BY receiveTimestamp
```

[my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAXYY.png)

However I would like to have a query that displays only the records with a maximum interval of 10 seconds around a specific date.

For example, in my case I would like to have only the records around the date 2023-02-02 15:20:29.740996 UTC (10 seconds before and after)

Can you help me please ?

Thank you by advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your requirement perfect for BigQuery table function.

See below input I created, it is very similar to your records in picture.

Based on your requirement, If I input datetime is row number 3

"2023-03-24 03:37:21.862011 UTC" then it should return row 2 and row 4 as they are within 10 seconds (before or after)

To achieve the results, see below table function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION mydataset.datetime_by_10seconds( inputDateTime TIMESTAMP)
AS (
  SELECT  *, 
       TIMESTAMP_DIFF(inputDateTime, timeinterval, SECOND) as dateTimeDiffInSeconds,
  FROM yourproject.mydataset.timeIntervalData
  WHERE TIMESTAMP_DIFF(inputDateTime, timeinterval, SECOND)  = 10 OR TIMESTAMP_DIFF(inputDateTime, timeinterval, SECOND)  = -10
);

-- call to table function
SELECT *
FROM mydataset.datetime_by_10seconds("2023-03-24 03:37:21.862011 UTC")
```

see below input and output

.
[Input]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPOab.png
[Output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq0aR.png